# PowerShell execute external command in same window

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute an external command using powershell, without having the second program to popup, I need to execute this program within the same PowerShell window and output both the log and the errors.
I started with this:

```
$outcome = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "dir" -NoNewWindow 2>&1
$outcome
```

But it doesn't work as expected. I still see the new window popping up with DOS and no redirect at all about the output, the errors and so on.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you use `Invoke-Expression` instead?

Comment: Yes I can but all the examples I found are Start-Process related ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
$outcome = Invoke-Expression "cmd.exe /c dir"
$outcome
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the call operator

```
& cmd.exe /c dir
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just run it.  You're missing "/c".  Otherwise, it just runs "cmd".

```
$outcome = cmd /c dir
```

With the added complication of start-process, you'd have to save the output to a file.

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c","dir" -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput cmd.log -RedirectStandardError err.txt
```

or

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath cmd.exe -Args "/c dir >cmd.log 2>&1" -NoNewWindow
```